# reference to angular's function from d3 data enter

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am trying to convert to scaled y using a function `xScale` and `yScale` defined in the angular component body in the d3 data enter.

```
drawPoints(points) {
  let g = this.view.append("g");

  let eles = g.selectAll("circle").data(points);

  eles
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", this.scale_x)
    .attr("cy", this.scale_y)
    .attr("r", 5);
}

scale_x(d) {
  return this.xScale(d[0]);
}

scale_y(d) {
  return this.yScale(d[1]);
}
```

However Chrome could not find the functions:

```
ZoomAndPanComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: this.xScale is not a function
at SVGCircleElement.scale_x (zoom-and-pan.component.ts:99)
at SVGCircleElement.<anonymous> (attr.js:29)
at Selection.each (each.js:5)
at Selection.attr (attr.js:53)
at ZoomAndPanComponent.drawPoints (zoom-and-pan.component.ts:93)
at ZoomAndPanComponent.initCanvas (zoom-and-pan.component.ts:65)
at ZoomAndPanComponent.ngOnInit (zoom-and-pan.component.ts:28)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:24503)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:35163)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:35102)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is the confusion on keyword `this` between the circle scope and angular component scope. Use `let that = this;` in `drawPoints` to keep angular component scope.

```
drawPoints(points) {
let g = this.view.append("g");

let eles = g.selectAll("circle").data(points);

let that = this;

eles
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return that.xScale(d[0]);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return that.yScale(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("r", 5);
```

}